# compare two iframes to execute if different with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, compare, var

I've been doing some coding to compare two iframes and if they are different it would execute but instead it stays dull, is it the .length and if it is what can i use instead ill supply  the code below its not much and im using two iframes, one with a auto clicker with js, two check a difference to update the page;

```
 var iframeContent1 = iframeDocument.getElementById('frame');

        var fr1 = Object.keys(iframeContent).length;
        var fr2 = Object.keys(iframeContent1).length;
  
        if(fr1 === fr2) {
```

Comment: How are you defining that two iframes are different? If they have different `src` attributes (i.e., are showing different content)? Right now, all you're doing is comparing how many properties each object reference has, which is somewhat meaningless.

Comment: If you compare `iframeContent === iframeContent1 ` it will be `true` if both `iframeContent` and `iframeContent1` are references to the same `<iframe>` DOM element.  There is no need for checking `.length`.

Comment: they both have the same src im using it as a way to update the website because one has a auto clicker one doesnt but the new 1 has more words

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that your end goal is clear and what exactly you expect to be different.

Comment: ok i have done that